# MySQL fulltext basic search, multiple words

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have the following code:

```
$dbLink = mysql_connect('localhost', 'tester', 'test');
mysql_select_db('acianetm_pcSpec', $dbLink);
$q = $_GET['q'];
$q = mysql_real_escape_string($q);
$sql = "
    SELECT *,
        MATCH(part) AGAINST ('$q') AS score
    FROM parts
    WHERE MATCH(part) AGAINST('$q')
"; 
$rest = MySQL_query($sql); 
while($row = MySQL_fetch_array($rest)) { 
echo "<br /> <strong>".$row['id']. " - ". $row['part']. " - $". $row['price']."</strong>"; 
}
```

When I load up http://site.com/q?=Nvidia it does not display any output.

MySQL Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `parts` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`part` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
`price` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`updated` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `part_2` (`part`),
FULLTEXT KEY `part` (`part`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=47 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The data inside the table:
`id  |#|   part                                                                       |#| price
 46 |#| (VIC Clayton Clearance) GIGABYTE 9800GT 512MB Nvidia Geforce GF9800GT DVI P... |#| 95.00

I have tried this SQL query: 
`SELECT * FROM parts WHERE part LIKE '%$q%'`

However without using str_replace eg.
`str_replace(' ', '&'. $q);`  it never worked for multiple words. Using the str_replace only made it work with 2 words, I need multiple.

**Doing this in PHPMyAdmin returns no rows** either, so what part of the query is wrong?

If someone could assist that would be great.

Thanks alot

Comment: not a php person, but most script languages don't expand variable values when the var identifier is inside single quotes. Try `SELECT * FROM parts WHERE part LIKE "%$q%"` .. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Omit the where clause in your sql statement.

Also the '?' in your URL should come before any name value pairs.

Comment: Omitting the where clause did nothing, same result. The place of `?` in the URL was a typo. Thanks. Code = `SELECT * FROM parts MATCH (part) AGAINST ('$q')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM parts
WHERE MATCH(part) AGAINST ('$q')";
```

Works well :-)